# Comparative date in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I need Comparative date in as3?

in start run read system date.

if date = 5/5/2015 gotoAndStop(1);

&

if date = 10/5/2015 gotoAndStop(2);

tanx.

Comment: Your question is impossible to understand. Your code is not valid code in any way. Please try again :)

Comment: Are you asking how to see if the current date is equal to a specific day? (5/5/2015 or 10/5/2015)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's comparing current date with set date:

```
var dCheck:Date = new Date('5/25/2015');
var dTemp:Date = new Date();
var dCurrent:Date = new Date(dTemp.fullYear,dTemp.month,dTemp.date);

if(dCheck.getTime() == dCurrent.getTime()){
    trace("success");
}
```

EDITED